# Getting target element from method (without event)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a sidebar that has various links

```html
<sidebar-link href="/dashboard" icon="HomeIcon" :is-active="isActive()" />
<sidebar-link href="/test" icon="TestIcon" :is-active="isActive()" />
```

If I give `isActive('/dashboard')`, it returns true/false based on the currentUrl and it works fine.

However, as this attribute already exists on the element (`href` tag), I was thinking if it was possible to get the current element inside this function.

I tried:

```html
<sidebar-link href="/dashboard" icon="HomeIcon" :is-active="isActive($event)" />
```

```js
methods: {
   isActive(e) {
      console.log(e); // this returns undefined
   }
}
```

Is there a way to pass the target element so that I can use like `e.target.href` in order to reduce repetition.

Comment: Are you using this to apply some style or some other logic?

Comment: I apply style based on the outcome (true/false)

Comment: Better not to run a method and directly do it in the template, will get the benefits of caching since the data will pretty much never change there while a `method` is always run.

Comment: Is `sidebar-link` a wrapper for `router-link` from `vue-router`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [$refs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements) like this to to target specific elements

```html
<sidebar-link ref="fancySidebarLink" />
```

```js
methods: {
   isActive(e) {
      console.log(this.$refs.fancySidebarLink)
   }
}
```

---

You could also `v-for` on all of your sidebar links and call your initial function on each iteration! (`isActive`)

Comment: So you suggest I have 20 refs for 20 sidebar elements? Think it's better to move this logic to child all together

Comment: I mean that you can pretty much apply this kind of solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67371066/8816585 It's not needed to have a lot of refs. You could loop on all of your link and interpolate them with something like `fancySidebarLinkHome`, `fancySidebarLinkAbout` etc but yeah, having the style directly set on the looping template itself is always better IMO. And check if `href="'/test' === $route.path"` directly into your `class/style` element property.

Comment: Did you found my linked answer interesting @senty?

Comment: I ended up moving the `isActive()` logic inside the component. That saved the day. I'll post here if an alternative comes to my mind