# change color depending on route in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, router

I need to change css color depending on the route or a prop for a route

For example:
if I go to home page the header needs to be red, If I go to the about page the header needs to be green

Ive tryed this with route props in my router.js but then I cant access them in the header component.

route.js

```
path: '/home',
    component: () => import('layouts/MainTemplate.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        name: 'home',
        css: 'red',
        component: () => import('pages/home')
      }
    ]
```

In my component I use the following

```
  props: ['css']
```

and to display the route css

```
{{ css }}
```

how can I do that with route props and that my header component can receive it if Im visiting for example home?

**update**, example can I pass to attributes like:

```
navbarCSS: {
        '/': Home: {
          image: url,
          style: #ddd
        }
      },
```

Comment: you can try vue router meta. `meta: {color: 'red'}`, and you can access this meta thru `this.$route.meta.color`. Then, you can use it in your components: `<foo :color="$route.meta.color"></foo>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that `css` is a supported key in `vue-router`.

Hence, you should probably better do it directly on the concerned navbar component like this

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="nav">
      <div :style="{ color: navbarColors[$route.path] }">Custom text in the navbar</div>
      <router-link to="/">Home</router-link> |
      <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
    </div>
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      navbarColors: {
        '/': 'red',
        '/about': 'blue',
      },
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Here, the `div` will toggle between `red` and `blue` depending if you're on the root or about page.
Here is a github repo example: https://github.com/kissu/so-vue-route-color (pretty much the default vue2 setup but in case it is needed)

Comment: thats a nice one, thanks, is it also possible to pass 2 css attributes like an object, Ive updated the main post.

Comment: To pass `queries` or `params`, you can use `$router.push` like this: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#router-push-location-oncomplete-onabort and get those in the receiving component with something for eg: `this.$route?.params?.image`.

Comment: Interresting, but I dont use routerpush to navigate to another page so I need another solution?

Comment: What do you use so ?

Comment: I use Quasar to handle that stuff

Comment: It is probably still using it behind the scene. Look into the documentation to find out how to pass your params with their API.