# Vue Navbar, Calling Function in Home.vue"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, navbar

I have a navbar item "logout" and I want to call the logout function which is placed in my `Home.vue`. The `Home.vue` component is controlled via the router. Is Navbar the child and Home.vue the parent?

This is my `App.vue`-

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Navbar />
    <router-view />
    <Footer />
    <footer>
      <cookie-law theme="base"></cookie-law>
    </footer>
  </div>
</template>
```

I've tried all the options listed in StackOverflow but no luck. Please give an example or link to the appropriate topic.

THX.

Comment: You could use [`refs`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67370693/8816585) to target the element and call the method on it.

Answer (score 1):

As per the application design and user case, User can perform `Logout` from any page in the application. Hence, Logout functionality should be globally available in the master page (`App.vue`) or in the common component (`Navbar.vue`) itself. By doing this we no need to write or call the logout logic from each and every component.

As navbar is a common component across the application and contains the `logout` button. I think best approach is to handle the logout functionality inside this component itself.

Navbar.vue **:**

```
<button @click="logout">Logout</button>

logout() {
  // Logout functionlity code. for ex. destroy session or cookie or reset any store data.
  // On success navigate the user to the login page 
}
```

Comment: Jindal: THX for your answer. I will follow your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you move the logout function to the  component or to the App.vue. and you can call that by [emit (component event)](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html) in vue.

example:

**Navbar.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="emitLogoutEvent">Logout</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    emitLogoutEvent() {
      this.$emit("logout");
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**App.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <Navbar @logout="logout"/>
    <!-- other code -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    logout() {
      // code for logout function
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: THX for your answer. Is it mandatory to install the function in App.vue or is this also possible in Home.vue?

Comment: @RalfBordé
I don't know why you want to call the logout function from Home.vue, But there are other options: 1. If you are using vue 3 you can write a vue composable and make your code reusable and call it everywhere you want. 2. You can call the logout function by Global Emit. 3. you can handle it by VUEX actions.
 If it's useful please hit the upvote button, thanks

Comment: OK, THX i will try this. I am using vue2 still.